# Where in Elixir's documentation is the method to call Erlang code described?

Tags: elixir

You can call functions in Erlang modules by prepending a colon:

`:erlang.time()`

...but where is this notation described in the [Elixir reference documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs.html)?

I ask because I'd prefer to use the straight docs to master Elixir, but I apparently need some initial bootstrapping information to understand how critical bits are organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is well known, but it's not mentioned in the reference documentation, where you have purely Elixir-specific stuff.

Just check the [official introduction to Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#calling-functions). The most valid part of it for you is:

> Note. Since Erlang modules are represented by atoms, you may invoke Erlang functions in Elixir as follows:

```
:lists.sort [3, 2, 1]
```

> All of the Erlang built-ins reside in the :erlang module.

Comment: Another thing to add is you can use `.module_info` to inspect Erlang modules, such as listing their methods. For example: `:lists.module_info`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's stated directly.  The name of each Erlang module is an atom.  Prefacing a string with a colon indicates the string is an atom. :*Module*. *function* simply resolves to a specific function in a module in Erlang.